# The filter function on my model return me <QuerySet []>

Tags: python, django, web, django-queryset, django-filter

**I have this models in my models.py**

I'm trying to send my Purchase details and return that as a `JSON`, but the
`myModel.objects.filter` function return me a void QuerySet objects

**models.py**

```
class Purchase(models.Model):
    total = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    user_phone = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    id_user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

class Purchase_detail(models.Model):
    id_product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id_purchase = models.ForeignKey(Purchase, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity= models.IntegerField()
    price = models.IntegerField()
```

**But when a trying to do `Purchase_detail.objets.filter` don't work**

```
def see_purchase_detail(request, id):
    if request.headers.get('X-Requested-With') == 'XMLHttpRequest':
        purchase_detail = json.loads(serializers.serialize(
            'json',
            Purchase_detail.objects.filter(id_purchase=id)
        ))
        print(purchase_detail, Purchase_detail.objects.filter(id_purchase=id))
        return JsonResponse({'details': purchase_detail}, safe=False)
    else:
        return JsonResponse({None}, safe=False)
```

Comment: I have not idea if its due to the id_purchase parameter is an ForeingKey

Answer (score 0):

I think your filter query shoul be something like this:

```py
Purchase_detail.objects.filter(id_purchase__id=id))
```

It is because how `ForeignKey` works in Django ORM. `id_purchase` in queries is `Purchase` object.

I think it would be better to rename `ForeignKey` fields.

```py
class Purchase(models.Model):
    total = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    user_phone = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

class Purchase_detail(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    purchase = models.ForeignKey(Purchase, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity= models.IntegerField()
    price = models.IntegerField()
```

And now filter should look like this:

```py
Purchase_detail.objects.filter(purchase__id=id))
```

Comment: Thanks for the data, my problem at this are the Purchase  id what I am trying to get don't have a purchase_detail in my bd because when i was created my models I was testing it